# How to fix Firefox dark theme for YouTube even dark theme is turned off?

Tags: firefox, themes, youtube

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Firefox quantum 59.0.1. But YouTube shows dark theme even the dark theme is turned off. I don't know why it is happening. Here is a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I fix this isuue?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the browser? If so what else have you tried.

Comment: No i haven't tried. But i have reinstalled firefox, however no result.

Comment: Try to clear cookie or cache by Ctrl + Alt + Delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your screenshot it seems you're using [Enhancer for YouTube™](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/enhancer-for-youtube/) Firefox add-on which is capable of overriding your theme only for YouTube.

To fix this, open preferences for the add-on, scroll down to **Theme** section and select "*Theme by default*".

[image]

Comment: I think the link you provided is broken.

Comment: Yeah.. i got it working. Thank you for the fix

Comment: @Jeff Could you try now and report? Probably something went temporarily wrong with addons.mozilla.org server. I just checked, it's opening the add-on page alright.

Comment: @pomsky yes, it is working now.